# How can we get row and section no of cell if cell is having button

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have groped table view and each section i have two rows in that rows i have multiple buttons
suppose i have clicked on section 0 in first cell button how can i get section no and row no of that cell.

Here is my cellforrow, I am getting row no but how to find out section no ??

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        [[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [[cell backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
         [cell.Mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCommentClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
     cell.Mybutton.tag=indexPath.row;
}

-(void)btnCommentClick:(id)sender
{
        UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;  
        NSLog(@"current Row=%d",senderButton.tag);
        NSIndexPath *path = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:senderButton.tag inSection:0];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to properly handle this is as follows. N.b. if you think this is a lot of extra and unnecessary work, you are either very lazy and a fan of Very Bad Design, or you are not getting how to set up smoothly designed OO code.

- create a custom UITableViewCell subclass
- set the target of the buttons to be the cell
- in the subclassed UITableVIewCell's .h file, create a protocol and a weak property on the tableViewCell that conforms to that protocol e.g.:

  ```
  @class MyTableViewCell

  @protocol MyTableViewCellDelegate
  - (void) leftButtonTappedOnTableViewCell: (MyTableViewCell *) cell;
  - (void) rightButtonTappedOnTableViewCell: (MyTableViewCell *) cell;
  @end

  @interface MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
  @property (nonatomic, weak) id< MyTableViewCellDelegate> delegate; 
  @end
  ```
- Make sure that the selector in the tableViewCell that gets called in respons to the buttons call one of the delegate methods, on the delegate property of the cell.
- Back in you viewController's cellForRowAtIndexPath, you should make sure that you use your UITableVIewCell subclass, and set the delegate to be the UIViewController. Then, implement the two delegate methods, and you can get the indexPath for the cell by asking the tableVIew for it:

  ```
  - (void) rightButtonTappedOnTableViewCell: (MyTableViewCell *) cell{
       NSIndexPath * indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell: cell];
      // ... do something now that you now the indexPath
  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
- (void) btnCommentClick:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

You can the section from indexPath.section

Comment: **Whoever downvoted this: Please comment.** I am using code like this in literally dozens of Apps without any problems. I would love to hear what's wrong with this approach.

Comment: I think they down voted it because its a bit of hack. The correct way is to use a delegate as said by Joride. Unfortunately I'm not 100% sure why one shouldn't use your answer. But I hate it when people down vote and don't leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The tableViewCell is a superview somewhere in the view hierarchy. You can iterate through the superviews to find the tableViewCell.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)cellForButton:(UIView *)button {
    if ([button.superview isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]])
        return button.superview; // Return found cell
    else if (button.superview)
        return [self cellForButton:button.superview]; // Find next superview
    else
        return nil; // No cell found
}
```

When found you can get the indexPath by:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self cellForButton:yourButton];
IndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: This is not good design, this is just a hacky way of quickly achieving something because you are lazy.

Comment: I agree with joride. This is a hack and you should use delegates as in joyrides answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can try by giving tag value for cell and other property like `accessibilityIdentifier` for section like below..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    [[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [[cell backgroundView] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     cell.Mybutton.tag = indexPath.row;
     cell.Mybutton.accessibilityIdentifier = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.section];
     [cell.Mybutton addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCommentClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
       }

}

-(void)btnCommentClick:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;  
    NSLog(@"current Row=%d current section =%d",senderButton.tag,[senderButton.accessibilityIdentifier intValue]);

}
```

Comment: Although this answer is clever, I would recommend to not use tags and certainly not the accessibilityIdentifier for these purposes.

Comment: Not a good idea to use. Definitely a hack. Though quite clever. I would use joride way.